# Picklist choice for flow

Tags: visual-workflow, picklist, visual-flows, dynamic-picklist

I have a field that stores comma separated values. We ask users in a free form text (string field) to add fruits they like, for example: Apple, Banana, Pineapple, Mango, etc.

On the flow screen, we want to show people choice set based on their entry in the string field. So picklist values will be different for each users.

I have tried few things so far including solution mentioned [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/201268/loop-through-comma-separated-values-in-visual-flow). I also tried Apex class that sends back List but I'm unable to populate it within the picklist field.

Has anyone faced a similar issue with Salesforce flows before? Is there any solution/workaround? I would like to avoid moving the string field to a child object.

Answer (score 1):

The [Quick Choice Flow Extension](https://unofficialsf.com/quick-choice-improved-picklists-and-radio-buttons-for-flow/) can take a comma-separated string of choices: